# DynamoDB and User Login table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've built an application and it currently has a fairly standard user table, as so:

int id, varchar email, varchar password

If I was to switch this to DynamoDB then how would I create this table?

If I use a hash key with the email address, then I'd not be able to offer the ability to update your email and if I used a hash to store the ID, then I'd need to use a scan which is expensive and restricted by a 1Mb limit.

Any advice please?
Thanks,
Mark

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12920884/268898

Comment: same issue for me

Answer (score 5):

Do you say that it would be expensive to use ID as hash because you need to filter by the email field?

If you need to filter your queries by an non-key column, you often ends creating an **index** for it.

**DynamoDB** has no built-in **secondary index**, but is quite simple to implement your own solution.

The main table could use **ID** as **hash**, as you pointed, and a differente table would serve as index, it could be:

```
varchar email, int id
```

Being **email** the hash key for the secundary table. If it's allowed to have multiple users with the same email, than you could use **ID** as range, to make things easier, otherwise a simple column would fit.

Comment: It's true that you can create your own secondary index in this way, but keep in mind that **your code is responsible for keeping it in sync with the main table**.  Also, operations to update the table and the index table will not be atomic.  That may or may not be a problem depending on how concurrent your access patterns are.

Comment: DynamoDB now has Global Secondary Indexes which can be used for this (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)

Comment: @JeffWalkerCodeRanger I don't see how GSIs can help solve this. Can you explain?

Comment: @RobertOliveira Simplt create a User table whose hash key is `ID` (i'd use guids not ints) with attributes of `Email` and `Password`.  Then create a Global Secondary index with a hash key of `Email`. You can then query the index by email.  When you update the User row you will have to do it by ID, but the index will automatically be kept in sync.

Comment: @JeffWalkerCodeRanger But does this provide an atomic operation when running a put? Wouldn't I need to query the GSI before executing the put operation?

Comment: @RobertOliveira Global indexes are eventually consistent with the table they are on.  That is still better than trying to maintain a separate index table yourself.  If you are updating an email address you will need to have the user's id.  If you don't already have it (say because they have logged in and you stored it in a cookie) then you will need to do a query on the index to get it first.

Answer (score 2):

Having a different table for indexing will result in high maintenance.
I came across a redundant model from my ex CTO.

For Your table : USER

**RDBMS:**

id, email password

*1, senthil3569@stack.com,asks*

**DynamoDB:**

KEY, id, email, password

*1,   1,  senthil3569@stack.com, asks*

*senthil3569@stack.com,1 , senthil3569@stack.com, asks*

Instead of storing one record , you are storing redundantly to fetch using non indexed columns.

Hope the solution is clear.

Comment: How does this solution require less maintenance than the one with secondary table? You again have 2 records and they can't be updated in a transaction, even if they are in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `User` table with hash key id(user UUID) and other attributes.
Create Global Secondary index with hash key Email and you have the option to choose sort key according to your requirement(User active status, Type of user).

- you can get them and update the user on UUID(user id)
- Get user with emailId
- Get user with active status without filter(On sort key)

```
UserTable:
   Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
   Properties:
     TableName: UserTable
     AttributeDefinitions:
       - AttributeName: id
         AttributeType: S
       - AttributeName: email
         AttributeType: S
       - AttributeName: status(optional sort key according to your requirement)
         AttributeType: S
     KeySchema:
       - AttributeName: id
         KeyType: HASH
     ProvisionedThroughput:
       ReadCapacityUnits: 5
       WriteCapacityUnits: 5
     GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
       - IndexName: UserDetail
         KeySchema:
           - AttributeName: email
             KeyType: HASH
           - AttributeName: status(option)
             KeyType: RANGE
         Projection:
           ProjectionType: ALL
         ProvisionedThroughput:
           ReadCapacityUnits: 5
           WriteCapacityUnits: 5
```